# Is useState meant to hold a custom object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

```
const [obj, set_obj] = useState(new CusObj())
```

Is there any difference between useState holding a primitive vs a custom object?

Comment: What do you mean _"meant to"_? `useState` doesn't care what value you pass to it, as long as you update it correctly (i.e. don't mutate `obj`) so changes can be detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

> Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does
> not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this
> behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread
> syntax:
>
> ```
> setState(prevState => {   
>   // Object.assign would also work
>   return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
> });
> ```
>
> Another option is useReducer, which is more suited for managing state
> objects that contain multiple sub-values.

For complex state values I would go with the [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook instead, but in short **yes** you can.

Comment: OP is asking about what can be stored in state, not how React state updates work. This answer isn't very relevant.

Comment: @DrewReese the short answer is yes, but it’s good to know the caveats imo